# Unable to find 'snapshot.ear', even after getting build success message

Tags: java, maven

First question.. Are these error messages marked in red colour affecting my build?
[image: console error messages and successful build messages]

Second question, where can i find my 1.0-Snapshot.war if it has successfully built?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First anwser : no, it doesn't affect your build. These are log related issues.

Second answer : build results usually ends in the target directory of your module/project.

But apparently you didn't build anything. That screenshot looks like a "clean" build. Maven clean goal doesn't build anything.